# transpose every n lines into a single line

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, paste

I am trying to bring bunch of n lines into a single line,not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

bunch of 11 words then a blank line and then again bunch of ll words and then blank like...so on.

## Example:

```
cat filename

hi
hello
how
are
you
i
am
fine
how
are
you

hi
how
is
she
doing
i 
have
not 
herd 
from
her

..
..
```

## desired output:

```
cat newFile

hi hello how are you i am fine how are you 
hi how is she doing i have not heard from her 
..
..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through awk.

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n/, " ")}1' file
hi hello how are you i am fine how are you
hi how is she doing i  have not  herd  from her
```

Comment: thanks this worked well for me, I had to use "dos2unix -c ASCII" on my file once to make this work.(problem with my file)

Comment: you may try `awk -v RS= '{gsub(/[\r\n]+/, " ")}1' file`

Answer (score 1):

Treating blocks of text separated by blank lines as a single record is known as paragraph mode in awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' file
hi hello how are you i am fine how are you
hi how is she doing i have not herd from her
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired output but transposes every 11 elements.

```
awk 'ORS=NR%11?FS:RS'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too (a bit long though):

```
#!/bin/bash
c=0
while read -r i
do
if [[ $i == "" ]]; then
line="$line""\n"
c=2
elif [[ $c == "2" || $c == "0" ]]; then
line="$line""$i"
c=1
else
line="$line"" ""$i"
fi
done <file1
echo -e "$line"
```

Ouptput:

```
hi hello how are you i am fine how are you
hi how is she doing i have not herd from her
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the assembled lines within your script, you can store each line in an array as you parse the file for later use:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i cnt=0
declare -a array

while read -r ln; do                            # read each line as ln
    [ "$ln" == "" ] && {                        # test for empty ln
        [ $cnt -gt 0 ] && {                     # if not first empty line
            while [ "${line:0:1}" == ' ' ]; do  # trim leading spaces from line
                line="${line:1}"
            done
            array+=( "$line" )                  # add line to array
            unset line                          # unset line
            continue                            # get next line
        }
        ((cnt++))                               # increment count
    }
    line+=" $ln"                                # append ln to line
done <"$1"
[ ${#line} -gt 0 ] && array+=( "$line" )        # if no trailing blank line

for ((a = 0; a < ${#array[@]}; a++)); do        # output array
    printf " array[%d]: %s\n" "$a" "${array[a]}"
done

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/bunchw.txt

hi
hello
how
are
you
i
am
fine
how
are
you

hi
how
is
she
doing
i
have
not
herd
from
her
```

**Output**

```
$ bash rdwordsline.sh dat/bunchw.txt
 array[0]: hi hello how are you i am fine how are you
 array[1]: hi how is she doing i have not herd from her
```